# Hi. I already set up payment for site, but i cant set up Order status and Basket history in admin panel

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

'''views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def stripe_webhook_view(request):
        payload = request.body
        sig_header = request.META['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
        event = None

        try:
            event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload, sig_header, settings.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET
          )
        except ValueError as e:
            # Invalid payload
            return HttpResponse(status=400)
        except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:

            return HttpResponse(status=400)


        if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
    # Retrieve the session. If you require line items in the response, you may include them by
            expanding line_items.
            session = stripe.checkout.Session.retrieve(
                event['data']['object']
            )

            line_items = session.line_items

            fulfill_order(line_items)


        return HttpResponse(status=200)


def fulfill_order(line_items):
    order_id = int(line_items.metadata.order_id)
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    order.update_after_payment()
```

'''

When i purchase smthng i expect to change **Order status** and **Basket history** in admin panel. Now after payment in admin panel **Order status** [doesn't change](https://prnt.sc/F6SoWkyYxjDT) (i need to get Paid) and **Basket history** inside order is [empty](https://prnt.sc/cfbpQvf1eAGZ).
I took this **Webhook** from [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#fulfill)